# Which are good practices for localized READMEs?

Tags: git, github, localization, gitlab, readme

Sometimes, there's the need to make READMEs available in more than one language in a project hosted in GitLab, GitHub, BitBucket, etc. In [this project](https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand), the author(s) created a main `README.md` in English, along with other `README-<lang>.md` files.

Is there a set of recommended good practices for that?

Comment: README content should be helpful and suitable for the intended audience. This likely varies across projects.

Comment: @DanWilson Yes, I know. My question is about localization.

Comment: May I ask why the downvoting? This question is about tools widely used by developers, and I did search before posting - could find nothing about the subject.

Comment: If you look at the [history](https://github.com/StreisandEffect/streisand/commits/master/README-fr.md) of the README files for streisand they appear to have been added as contributors felt there was a need. Built-in support for localized README files is an [outstanding request](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/899) at GitHub. If you want to create localized files then just follow what other projects are doing. I didn't downvote, BTW.

Comment: @DanWilson This link leads to really good examples, like [this](https://github.com/tiimgreen/github-cheat-sheet/blob/master/README.md#github-cheat-sheet-), where the authors added localized READMEs in files named `README-<Lang>.md`, then added in each one links for the other languages. Sounds like a good guideline. Unfortunately, there seems to be nothing close to a "standard".

Comment: I have the same question. I upvoted you and downvoted the unrelated reply. pls update it if you have got an answer.

Comment: I guess this depends on github/gitlab. If they like it they can support it easily, just pick one of the readmes per the browser locale. So you'd try to reach them and request the feature.